# What xaml control is this (screenshot)?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Does someone know the name of this control, from the screenshot of the Windows Phone XBox-Music App? I couldn't find anything.[image]

Comment: You may take a look at [AutoSuggestBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox.aspx), also [here at blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/buildingapps/archive/2014/07/22/tips-and-tricks-for-using-xaml-controls-in-your-universal-windows-apps.aspx).